# Which spaces exactly are ignored by \halign?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

Some spaces seem ignored by the `\halign` primitive. For instance,

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\halign{ # \cr \space b \cr}}
\showbox0
```

indicates that there is no glue before `b`, but that there are two spaces after. It seems that spaces in the preamble are lost as soon as it is read, but I can't be sure.

> Which spaces (implicit spaces, funny spaces, macros expanding to spaces, other spaces) are lost where in `\halign`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reading the "u"-part of the preamble for each column of an `\halign`, namely the part which will be inserted before the cell contents, TeX ignores any leading "spacer".  In this context, a "spacer" is defined as any implicit or explicit character token with category code 10.  See `@<Scan the template \<u_j>...@>=` in tex.web for those who understand Pascal code.

At the start of each cell, i.e., just after each `&` or `\cr` (or `\crcr`), TeX fully expands tokens and ignores "spacers".  This is done by calling `@<Get the next non-blank non-call token@>` before any call to `init_col`.

A test to show that indeed arbitrary implicit space tokens are ignored:

```
% Define \sp as an implicit space token "q".
\lccode` =`q\def\\{\let\sp= }\lowercase{\\ }

% Store an \halign in a box. The \sp in the u-part
% preamble is completely ignored, directly when TeX
% stores the preamble.  To prove this, we redefine
% \sp globally, and see that it doesn't appear at
% the next line.
%
\setbox0=\vbox{\halign{
  \sp x # \cr
  \sp \space A\gdef\sp{!} \cr
  \space B \cr
}}
% Show the box.  Leading spaces have all been ignored.
% Not trailing spaces.
\tracingall\showbox0
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about implicit spaces, but after `&` or `\cr`, tokens are expanded (looking for `\omit` or `\noalign`) until an unexpandable token is found. Spaces are ignored in both cases.

Comment: but spaces are also ignored within the preamble?

Comment: @Bruno: No. It looks like the space after the `{` is ignored, but the space following the `#` is certainly there. A preamble of ` a # \cr` inserts a space before and after the `b`.

Comment: right. So spaces would only be ignored at the beginning of the `u` part of the template, perhaps.

Comment: @Bruno: That would be consistent with ignoring spaces after `&`.